# Does $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\lim \int f_n \rightarrow \int f$ imply $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The full question from this practice qual:

> True/False: Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be any measure space. If $f_n,f \in L^1(\mu)$ are measurable functions, $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\lim \int f_n \rightarrow \int f$, then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\mu)$.

I recognize that the question is essentially asking if I can move the limit inside the integral. The three theorems I have which allow me to do this are: Monotone Convergence Theorem, Fatou's Lemma, and Dominated Convergence Theorem. Since I don't have any increasing sequences of functions or dominating function, I would think if the answer is true, I need to use Fatou's Lemma. But I don't see any way to use Fatou's Lemma to justify it is true (the fact the question says "any" measure space signals to me it may be false, but I've been unable to construct a counter example)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff So Fatou's Lemma says that $\int 2|f| \leq \liminf \int (|f|+|f_n|)-|f_n-f|$?

Comment: It happens if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n| =\int_X |f|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False.

Take $f = 0$.

$f_n = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0, n]} -\frac {1}{n} \chi_{[-n, 0)}$.

$f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$ a.e.

But $\int |f_n| = 2$. So $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Doesn't this not satisfy the condition $\lim \int f_n \rightarrow \int f$?

Comment: $\int f_n = 0$ right?

Comment: (Note my comments shows this is true for positive functions, and this shows this is the only obstruction.)

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal Ah I misread the $f_n$ function. So it's false in general but true if $f_n \geq 0$ a.e.?

Comment: @brenton no it is not true even if the functions are non negative

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake: it is true if you assume that $|f_n|_1\to |f|_1$. Take $g_n = (|f|+|f_n|)-|f_n-f|$. By hypothesis $g_n\to 2|f|$ almost everywhere and $g_n\geqslant 0$, so Fatou says...?

This holds in general for $L^p$ spaces: if $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere and $|f_n|_p \to |f|_p$, then $|f-f_n|_p\to 0$. Again, taking $g_n= 2^{p-1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p) - |f_n-f|^p$ gives by Fatou the result.

This is one of many results due to Riesz.

In particular, it is true if $f_n$ is positive almost everywhere.

---

Note the above gives a very easy proof the simple functions are dense in $L^p$ for any finite $p$: just manufacture a sequence of simple functions that tend pointwise and in norm to your function, which is easy!

Comment: So Fatou's Lemma says that $\int 2|f| \leq \liminf \int (|f|+|f_n|)-|f_n-f|$?

Comment: Ok and then I can isolate the $|f_n -f|$ term, and show it converges to $0$?

Comment: You get that $\int 2 |f| \leqslant 2\int |f|-\limsup |f_n-f|_1 $; or that $\limsup |f_n-f|_1 \leqslant 0$!

Comment: Haha, I made a mistake and was thinking $\lim \text{inf}\, |f_n - f| \le 0$. But I think even that is enough to say that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$?

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal That is the definition of $L^1$ convergence: if $\limsup x_n=0$ and $x_n$ is nonnegative, $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: No, I mean $\lim \text{ inf} \, |f_n - f| \le 0$ in this case also proves that $f_n \to f$ right? Given any subsequence of the $f_n$'s we can get a further subsequence converging to $f$.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal No. Consider $x_n=0$ if $n$ is even and $x_n=1$ if $n$ is odd. Then $x_n$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: Please read my comments. Does any subsequence have a further subsequence converging to $0$ in your example?

Comment: All I am saying is even if someone proves that $\lim  \text{inf} |f_n - f| = 0$ in this case, one actually proves that given any subsequence of $f_n$ there exists a further subsequence converging  to $f$. But that implies that the original sequence $f_n$ has to converge to $f$. Because otherwise, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|| f_{n_k} - f|| > \epsilon $. But then $f_{n_k}$ has no subsequence converging to $f$, contrary to what we proved.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal OK.